# Existence a path of a smooth manifold

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Given a continuous differentiable functio $F:\mathbb{R}^n\mapsto \mathbb{R}^m$ with $n>m$. Define
$$
{\cal M}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: F(x)=0\}
$$
and let $x_0\in{\cal M}$ such that the Jacobian of function $F$ at $x_0$, say $JF(x_0),$ has full-rank $m$.

Suppose that $r\in\mathbb{R}^n$ for which $JF(x_0)r=0.$ I wish to construct a path on ${\cal M}$ through $x_0$ with direction $r$ that means finding a continuous differentiable $p:(-a,a)\mapsto {\cal M}$ with small $a>0$ such that $p(0)=x_0$ and $p'(0)=r$.

Note tha if we define $p$ by $p(t)=x_0+tr$ then $p(0)=x_0$ and $p'(0)=r$ but $p(t)\notin{\cal M}$ because 
$$
F(p(t))=F(x_0)+tJF(x_0)r+o(|t|)=o(|t|)
$$
and we know $o|t|$ is not really zero. So, there should be a modification on $p$. Any advice or suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have observed, there is not going to be any simple minded formula. Instead, you can apply the Implicit Function Theorem, the conclusion of which gives you a parameterization $\phi : U \to \mathcal{M}$, $\phi(0) = x_0$, where $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{n-m}$ is open. Once you have that, defining paths in $\mathcal{M}$ becomes easy: assuming (as you must) that the vector $r$ is in  $\text{image}(d\phi_0)$, take $v = (d\phi_0)^{-1}(r)$, take $q(t)=tv$, then take $p(t) = \phi(q(t))$.

Comment: Thanks @Lee for your answer. What do you mean with $\phi_0$? Is it $\phi(0)$? And how will we get such paramerezation by [Implicit Function Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem)?

Comment: The expression $d\phi_0$ means the derivative of the map $\phi$ at $0$, thought of as a maximal rank linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^{n-m}$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ whose image is the tangent space of $\mathcal{M}$ at $\phi(0)=x_0$.

Comment: I will quote from the Wikipedia link you provided, changing the expression to fit the variables of our discussion: "one can in principle (though not necessarily with an analytic expression) express the ... variables $x_i$ in terms of the ... variables $u$ as $x_i = \phi_i(u)$, at least in some disk." That is the desired parameterization.

Comment: I understand. But, isn't the condition $JF(x_0)r=0$ enough to guarantee the existence of such path?

Comment: Yes, $JF(x_0)r=0$ is equivalent to my requirement that $r$ is in $\text{image}(d\phi_0)$.

Comment: I guess so. But, how will we justify it? I am thinking of reversing the function $F$. I mean that we can see $\phi$ as the inverse of $F$ so its Jacobian is the inverse of $JF(x_0)$. DO you have another clearer view?

Comment: That equivalence is just linear algebra, following by applying the derivative operator to both sides of the equation $F(\phi(u))=0$ to get $dF_{x_0} \circ d\phi_0 = 0$ and using that $JF$ (which I write $dF_{x_0}$) has rank $m$ and that $d\phi_0$ has rank $n-m$. The intuitive idea of "Reversing the function $F$" is exactly what the implicit function theorem allows you to do rigorously.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31800/discussion-between-jlamprong-and-lee-mosher).

Comment: What I wrote implies that $\text{kernel}(dF_{x_0}) = \text{image}(d\phi_0)$.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a vector field -- the constant field that's $r$ at every point. It's tangent to $M$ at $x_0$, right?

How about letting $F(x)$, for any $x$, be the orthogonal projection of $r$ along the nullspace of $JF(x)$?*  Now the restriction of $F$ to $M$ will be a tangent field on $M$, and hence its integral curves will lie in $M$.

- To be clear: pick an orthonormal basis for the nullspace, n_1, ..., n_k, and let

$$F(x) = r - (r \cdot n_1) n_1 + ... + (r \cdot n_k) n_k 
$$

Observe that $F$ is nonzero in a neighborhood of $x_0$ by continuity.

Comment: Thank @John for your answer. But, I am not familiar with tangent field and integral curve. Can you elaborate more detail please?

Comment: Alas, no, for then I'd be writing a book on differential topology rather than answering an MSE question. But a "tangent field" for a manifold $M$ in $\mathbb R^n$ just means a vector field on $M$ where the vector, at each point, is actually tangent to $M$ rather than pointing somewhere else. Example: on the unit circle in $\mathbb R^2$,  the vector field $F(x, y) = [-y, x]$ is a tangent field on the circle, but $G(x, y) = [1, 0]$ is tangent to the circle only at $(0, \pm 1)$, hence is not a tangent field.